# Is it possible to run all tests with raco test from folder?

Tags: racket

I always run tests in this way: raco test filename.rkt. Is there a built-in possibility to run all my test modules (module+ test ...) in folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raco test directory/` recursively runs tests on all .rkt files in the given directory and its subdirectories.

You can use `raco test .` for the current working directory.

Comment: You might prefer `raco test -y dir`, which rebuilds outdated compiled zo files too.